# How do I rearrange the cards in ascending order django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a page where the customer name in the cards is not rearrange in ascending order via alphabetical order Ex: B,M,S. How do I make it to arrange in alphabetical order so that the cards with the customer name Bangkok airways will appear first follow by the cards with malaysia airlines will appear next and so on?

[image]

views.py

```
def outgoinggallery(request):
    user = request.user

    category = request.GET.get('category')

    if category == None:
        alloutgoinglru = OutgoingLRU.objects.filter(category__user=user)
    else:
        alloutgoinglru = OutgoingLRU.objects.filter(category__name=category, category__user=user)
        # if query:
        # return OutgoingLRU.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)



    categories = Category.objects.filter(user=user)
    context = {'categories': categories, 'alloutgoinglru': alloutgoinglru}

    return render(request, 'Outgoing/outgoinggallery.html', context)
```

outgoinggallery.html

```
{% extends "logisticbase.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>



td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
        .image-thumbail {
            height: 200px;
            object-fit: cover;
        }


        .list-group-item a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>




    <br>


   <div style="padding-left:16px">

        <div class="row">


            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <h5>View Outgoing LRU</h5>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                    
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">

                    {% for OutgoingLRU in alloutgoinglru %}
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card my-4">
                            <img class="image-thumbail" src="{{OutgoingLRU.image.url}}" >

                            <div class="card-body">
                                <small>Customer Name: {{OutgoingLRU.category.name}}</small>
                                <br>
                                <small>Delivery Order: {{OutgoingLRU.Deliveryor}}</small>
                            </div>
                            <a href="{% url 'viewlruphoto' OutgoingLRU.id %}"  style="width:265px" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm m-1">View</a>
                            <form action="{% url 'deleteoutgoing' OutgoingLRU.id %}" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <button type="submit" style="width:270px" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% empty %}
                    <h3>No photos...</h3>
                    {% endfor %}








                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>


{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
class OutgoingLRU(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'OutgoingLRU'
        verbose_name_plural = 'OutgoingLRUs'

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    equipmentimages = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    boximages = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    documentimage = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)

    datetime = models.DateTimeField()  # datetime is the date and time the form was created
    serialno = models.TextField()  # serialno stand for serial number
    partno = models.TextField()  # partno stand for part number
    Deliveryor = models.TextField()  # deliveryor stand for delivery order
    MCO = models.TextField()
    descriptionequipment = models.TextField()  # A short description about the equipment (*Optional)
    descriptionequipmentbox = models.TextField()  # A short description of the equipment in the box (*optional)
    descriptionbox = models.TextField()  # A short description of the box (*optional)
    document = models.TextField()  # A short description of the delivery note document (*optional)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.descriptionequipment
```

Comment: Show us your models please.

Comment: sure, the models I have is to add to the database

Comment: ok, i have edited my question with the models.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
      User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
   
    class Meta:
       ordering = ('name',)
       verbose_name = 'Category'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name


class OutgoingLRU(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    equipmentimages = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    boximages = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    documentimage = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)

    datetime = models.DateTimeField()  # datetime is the date and time the form was created
    serialno = models.TextField()  # serialno stand for serial number
    partno = models.TextField()  # partno stand for part number
    Deliveryor = models.TextField()  # deliveryor stand for delivery order
    MCO = models.TextField()
    descriptionequipment = models.TextField()  # A short description about the equipment (*Optional)
    descriptionequipmentbox = models.TextField()  # A short description of the equipment in the box (*optional)
    descriptionbox = models.TextField()  # A short description of the box (*optional)
    document = models.TextField()  # A short description of the delivery note document (*optional)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'OutgoingLRU'
        verbose_name_plural = 'OutgoingLRUs
        ordering = ('category__name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descriptionequipment
```

after that:
**1)run python manage.py makemigrations**
**2)run python manage.py migrate**

Comment: ok, thanks for the help, it works now :)

Comment: HI @amadou sow, do you mind helping me with this questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69370717/get-the-default-value-from-a-list-django

Comment: @Shadowwalker i answered your question.

Comment: HI @amadou sow, thanks for the help, I have another issue is how do I make the action done go to step 2 when the user edit the table for the serial number for example?

Comment: @Shadowwalker I have answered your question

Comment: sorry to disturb you again, able to help me out with this question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69535149/allow-users-to-sort-in-ascending-order-using-radio-button-django

Answer (score 1):

Ascending:
`alloutgoinglru = alloutgoinglru.order_by('category__name')`

Descending:
`alloutgoinglru = alloutgoinglru.order_by('-category__name')`

Comment: Hi, i try to put under my views.py it does not work

Comment: @amadousow can i check what does the ordering do? cause when i add the ordering it gives me an error

Comment: @Shadowwalker where did you add that ordering in Category or OutgoingLRU ?

Comment: huh, there is no ordering in my db tho

Comment: @Shadowwalker inside your models OutgoingRU try to add this class Meta:
    ordering = ('category__name', )

Comment: ok, i try and still the same issue, the cards wont rearranged in ascending order for the customer name

Comment: @Shadowwalker what if you add it inside models Category something like class Meta: ordering = ('name', )?

Comment: hmm, it still does not work :(

Comment: i try adding this .order_by('category__name')  behind the get also wont work

Comment: my customer name is in the category btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237548/discussion-between-amadou-sow-and-shadowwalker).