# Get the default value from a list django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a website with a list of status, how do I only retrieve the steps 1 from the list i created when my form is submitted and store into the database?

models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    STEP1 = "step 1"
    STEP2 = "step 2"
    STEP3 = "step 3"
    STEP4 = "step 4"

    STATUS = (
        (STEP1, 'Received'),
        (STEP2, 'Cleaning'),
        (STEP3, 'Leak '),
        (STEP4, 'Loss Pressure Test'),

    )

    Datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    serialno = models.TextField()  # serialno stand for serial number
    partno = models.TextField()  # partno stand for part number
    reception = models.TextField()
    Customername = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reception
```

forms.py

```
class AddForm(forms.Form):
    reception = forms.CharField(label='',
                                widget=forms.TextInput(
                                    attrs={"class": 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter reception number'}))
    partno = forms.CharField(label='',
                             widget=forms.TextInput(
                                 attrs={"class": 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter part number'}))
    serialno = forms.CharField(label='',
                               widget=forms.TextInput(
                                   attrs={"class": 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Serial Number'}))
    Customername = forms.CharField(label='',
                                   widget=forms.TextInput(
                                       attrs={"class": 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter customer name'}))

    class meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('reception', 'partno', 'serialno', 'Customername')
```

views.py

```
def addPhoto(request):
    msg = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Datetime = datetime.now()
            reception = form.cleaned_data['reception']
            partno = form.cleaned_data['partno']
            serialno = form.cleaned_data['serialno']
            Customername = form.cleaned_data['Customername']
            # create a new MCO object with the form data
            form = Photo(Datetime=Datetime, reception=reception, partno=partno, serialno=serialno, Customername=Customername)
            form.save()
            context = {'form': form}
            return redirect('/gallery', context)
        else:
            msg = 'form is not valid'
    else:
        form = AddForm()

    return render(request, 'photos/add.html', {'form':  form,})
```

This is the page where user enter the details:
[image]

this is the page where the details are being display (Under the action done, it should display step 1 which is the received whenever user submit the form, how do i do that?:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the `.html` file where the details are being display ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do this you can create a field call status inside your database so that by default the value will be default = STEP1 something like this:

```
 class Photo(models.Model):
        STEP1 = "Received"
        STEP2 = "Cleaning"
        STEP3 = "Leak"
        STEP4 = "Loss Pressure Test"
    
        STATUS = (
            (STEP1, 'Received'),
            (STEP2, 'Cleaning'),
            (STEP3, 'Leak '),
            (STEP4, 'Loss Pressure Test'),
    
        )
    
        Datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        #i add the status here so by default it is just "Received"
        status  = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=STATUS,
            default=STEP1)
    
        serialno = models.TextField()  # serialno stand for serial number
        partno = models.TextField()  # partno stand for part number
        reception = models.TextField()
        Customername = models.TextField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.reception
```

After that
**1) run makemigrations and migrate** 
Now inside your templates you can just call "your_instance.status" .

Comment: Thanks, it work, but how do i make it so that when the user edit the table, the action done will show step2?

Comment: @Shadowwalker if you have a new question, ask it separately from this one and include a link to this one if it might be useful. Don't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Hi sorry about this, I will open up another question in the future

Answer (score 1):

**An answer for your other question:
how do i make it so that when the user edit the table, the action done will show step2?**
let us do something like this.
forms.py:

```
from .models import Photo


class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['serialno','partno','reception','Customername']
```

views.py

```
from .forms import PhotoForm
from .models import Photo
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
def editphoto(request,photo_id):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo,pk=photo_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhotoForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #we can do something like this to check that serial number has changed 
            if form.serialno != photo.serialno:
                form.serialno = 'Cleaning'
                form.save()
            return redirect('***somewhere***')
    else:
        form = PhotoForm(instance=photo)
    return render(request,'your-template',{'form':form})
```

but note that there is a security concerns here i did not actually checks that the user is the author of that post.so basically now any user can edit a post,that is so bad.to avoid this you can just create a foreign key to User(model) inside Photo and inside your views.py you can check that just do something like:**photo = get_object_or_404(Photo,pk=photo_id,author_id=request.user.pk)** now when the user is not the author of the post it will raise Not Found Page,That is it.
Happy Coding.

Comment: "_answer for your other question_"... **Don't** do this, if the OP asks something separate tell them to ask a _new_ question. See [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @Shadowwalker did this answer your question ?

Comment: hi, I am still trying to solve one of my issue, will let u know if i can solve

Comment: @amadousow Sorry to disturb u again, able to help me with this error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69387109/addform-object-has-no-attribute-reception

Comment: @Shadowwalker let us go to the chat that we talk last time.

Comment: @amadousow sorry to disturb you again, not sure if you can help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474742/filter-the-number-of-pages-not-working-django