# 'verifyForm' object has no attribute 'reception'

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a page where it allows the user to enter the reception number, so when the user enter the reception number, it should verify with the database if the reception number exist, but i am having this error: `'verifyForm' object has no attribute 'reception'`. How do I solve this error?
Updated with traceback error

views.py

```
@login_required()
def verifydetails(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Customername = request.GET['Customername']
        form = AddForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.reception == Photo.reception:
            messages.success(request, 'Both Reception and customer name match')
            return redirect('AddMCO')

        else:
            messages.success(request, 'Both Reception and customer do not match')
            return redirect('verifydetails')


    else:
        form = AddForm()

    return render(request, 'verifydetails.html', {'form': form, })
```

forms.py

```
class verifyForm(forms.Form):
    reception = forms.CharField(label='',
                              widget=forms.TextInput(
                                  attrs={"class": 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Reception number'}))

    class meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('reception')
```

verifydetails.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
      });
    </script>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>SCS verify details</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Moment.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-VBLiveTKyUZMEzJd6z2mhfxIqz3ZATCuVMawPZGzIfA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" integrity="sha256-XPTBwC3SBoWHSmKasAk01c08M6sIA5gF5+sRxqak2Qs=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js" integrity="sha256-z0oKYg6xiLq3yJGsp/LsY9XykbweQlHl42jHv2XTBz4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
{% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss = "alert">x</button>
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
<body class="m-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>Verify Details</h3>

                <a href="{% url 'customer' %}" class="btn btn-dark my-3">Go Back</a>
                <div class="card" style="width: 400px">


                     <form  method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="form-group m-3">
                            <label>Reception:</label>
                            <br>
                            {{ form.reception}}
                        </div>


                        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary m-3">Submit</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

traceback error in my code is this:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/verifydetails/

Django Version: 2.2.20
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account.apps.AccountConfig',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "E:\Role_based_login_system-master\account\views.py" in verifydetails
  496.                 if form.reception == Photo.reception:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /verifydetails/
Exception Value: 'verifyForm' object has no attribute 'reception'
```

Comment: The form code you've added in your question is `verifyForm` not `AddForm`.

Comment: Hi, I change to verifyform and it give me this error also 'verifyForm' object has no attribute 'reception'

Comment: ok, Will update my question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

`form = AddForm(request.POST or None)` This line says that `form` can also be `None` if object is not found.

---

You're trying to run this line `if form.reception == Photo.reception:` before checking if form is valid or `None`.

---

To solve this problem, do something like:

```
if form:
    if form.reception == Photo.reception:
         ........
else(optional):
    print("the object doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Hi, it still give me the same issue 'verifyForm' object has no attribute 'reception'

Comment: I have reception in my form.py tho

Comment: @Shadowwalker change this class verifyForm(forms.Form) to class verifyForm(forms.ModelForm) and try it.

Comment: @Shadowwalker and instead of {{ form.reception}} just use {{ form.as_p }}.

Comment: @amadou sow, I got this error for putting modelform, ModelForm has no model class specified.

Answer (score 0):

Change `form.reception` to `form.cleaned_data["reception"]`