# Filter the number of pages not working django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, paginator

I have a page where it will display the details that is in my database in a form of a table, I am doing a filtering so when the list gets very long at least it can split up into different pages instead of user scrolling through, but I tried and nothing came out, not sure if I am doing correctly or not.

This is what I wanted as shown in the picture below but it is not displaying.

[image]

ViewMCO.html

```
    {% extends "customerbase.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <style>
    table {
        border-collapse:separate;
        border:solid black 1px;
        border-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
    }
    
    td, th {
        border-left:solid black 1px;
        border-top:solid black 1px;
    }
    
    th {
        border-top: none;
    }
    
    td:first-child, th:first-child {
         border-left: none;
    }

    
    
    
    </style>
    <script>
      
    
     // Function to download table data into csv file
            function download_table_as_csv(table_id, separator = ',') {
                var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
                var csv = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
                    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                        var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
                        data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
                        row.push('"' + data + '"');
                    }
                    csv.push(row.join(separator));
                }
                var csv_string = csv.join('\n');
                var filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.style.display = 'none';
                link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            };
    
    </script>
    
    
       <div style="padding-left:16px">
         <br>
    
    
     <div class="form-block">
         <h6>Search for Part Number/ Serial Number/ Reception Number/ MCO Number/ Customer Name/ Status</h6>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'ViewMCO' %}" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'/>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
         <br>
       <table id="viewTable" class="m-2">
            <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="#" onclick="download_table_as_csv('viewTable');">Download as CSV</a>
           <br>
    
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Latest Log</th>
          <th>Part Number</th>
          <th>Serial Number</th>
          <th>Reception Number</th>
          <th>MCO Number</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
             {% for photo in allusername %}
    
    
      <tr>
            <td>{{photo.Datetime}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.partno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.serialno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.reception}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.mcoNum}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.Customername}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.status}}</td>


          <td>
          <form action="{% url 'customerdetails' photo.id %}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">View</button>
          </form>
          </td>
      </tr>
    
    {% endfor %}
    
    </table>
         <br>
    {% if allusername.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if allusername.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ allusername.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in allusername.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if allusername.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if allusername.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ allusername.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}

    
    
    </div>
       </div>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required()
def ViewMCO(request):
    search_post = request.GET.get('q')
    if (search_post is not None) and search_post:
        allusername = Photo.objects.filter(Q(reception__icontains=search_post) | Q(partno__icontains=search_post) | Q(
            Customername__icontains=search_post) | Q(mcoNum__icontains=search_post) | Q(status__icontains=search_post)
                                           | Q(serialno__icontains=search_post))
        if not allusername:
            allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime")

    else:
        allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime")
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(allusername, 10)
        try:
            allusername = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            allusername = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            allusername = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)



    context = {'allusername': allusername}
    return render(request, 'ViewMCO.html', context)
```

Comment: It might be because you don't paginate when there is a value for `q`?

Comment: The q i use it for my search bar tho, not sure if it will affect?

Comment: Does it work if you don't have anything in your search bar?

Comment: as mean i remove the q code?

Comment: Ah no i mean make the view process the `else` part. If your view goes through `if (search_post is not None) and search_post`, there is no pagination being done

Comment: nope just try still the same, nothing come out

Comment: do not work tho

Comment: is my code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your views.py there is a problem of indentation and you should pass the search_post in the template

```
@login_required()
def ViewMCO(request):
    search_post = request.GET.get('q')
    if (search_post is not None) and search_post:
        allusername = Photo.objects.filter(Q(reception__icontains=search_post) | Q(partno__icontains=search_post) | Q(
            Customername__icontains=search_post) | Q(mcoNum__icontains=search_post) | Q(status__icontains=search_post)
                                           | Q(serialno__icontains=search_post))
        if not allusername:
            allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime")
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        paginator = Paginator(allusername, 10)
        try:
            allusername = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            allusername = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            allusername = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)



        context = {'allusername': allusername,'query':search_post}
        return render(request, 'ViewMCO.html', context)
    else:#if search_post is None 
        return redirect('somewhere')
```

and now in your template there is work to do.
change this

```
 {% if allusername.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if allusername.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ allusername.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in allusername.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if allusername.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if allusername.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ allusername.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

to

```
 {% if allusername.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if allusername.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&page={{ allusername.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in allusername.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if allusername.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if allusername.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&page={{ allusername.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

what i change in the pagination is that i passed the 'query' in the template and i use urlencode.

Comment: Maybe add a handling for when `search_post = request.GET.get('q')` returns `None`

Comment: still dont work tho, idk why it is not displaying

Comment: @Shadowwalker be sure to have enough data and to write exactly what i wrote here.it should work.

Comment: enough data as mean?

Comment: paginator = Paginator(allusername, 10)  be sure to have at least 11 becuause if it is less than 10 then the padignation is not seeing.you can change 10 by putting 1 and test it.

Comment: @amadousow so if i put 5 will show only 5 data per page am i correct?

Comment: @Shadowwalker yes and i updated my answer in your views.py there was an other problem of logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237912/discussion-between-amadou-sow-and-shadowwalker).

Comment: @amadousow able to help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639566/move-a-data-from-one-department-to-another-using-django

Comment: @amadousow able to help me with this questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848238/how-to-retrieve-the-data-from-the-database-and-display-it-in-a-textbox-for-users

Comment: @amadousow right now I have an issue with the pagination part and sorting my data in ascending order, i not sure why when i click on the next page, all the data from my database will appear, able to help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70028949/how-can-i-make-pagination-to-work-with-filtering-django

Comment: @Shadowwalker join me on this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239382/discuss-django

Comment: @amadousow sorry i saw the message now