# How to retrieve the data from the database and display it in a textbox for users to update it

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a webpage where it is supposed to allow users to update the data from the database but the data is unable to display in the textbox, how do I make it able to display it in the textbox?

This is my current webpage where the users need to manually type in all the data they want to update inside the text box.
[image]

What I wanted is like this, the data is already retrieve from the database for the users to see, and let say they want to update the customer name, they just need to chnage the customer name and click on the submit button to update it, how do I make it able to retrieve the data?
[image]

views.py

```
@login_required()
def updatedata(request, id):
    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Photo.mcoNum = request.POST.get('mcoNum')
        Photo.reception = request.POST.get('reception')

        form = UpdateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('logdata')
    else:
        form = UpdateForm

    return render(request, 'updatedata.html', {'form': form})
```

updatedata.html

```
<!doctype html>
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<br><br>
    <h2 class="text-center">Edit Log Data</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-secondary">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mcoNum = forms.CharField(label="", widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "MCO Number"}))
    reception = forms.CharField(label="", max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "reception"}))
    partno = forms.CharField(label="", max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Part Number"}))
    serialno = forms.CharField(label="", max_length=100,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Serial Number"}))
    Customername = forms.CharField(label="", max_length=100,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Customer Name"}))
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ("mcoNum", "reception", "partno", "serialno", "Customername",)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.you have to pass the instance(photo) in the form.

```
@login_required()
def updatedata(request, id):
    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Photo.mcoNum = request.POST.get('mcoNum')
        Photo.reception = request.POST.get('reception')

        form = UpdateForm(request.POST,instance=photo)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('logdata')
    else:
        form = UpdateForm(instance=photo)

    return render(request, 'updatedata.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: eh, it does not work, try it before, the text box just wont display the data

Comment: @Shadowwalker create a chat and we will discuss it.

Comment: @Shadowwalker add the url in the action in the form `<form action = '{% url 'your-url-of-updatedata' %} method="POST">`

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238895/how-to-retrieve-the-data-from-the-database-and-display-it-in-a-textbox-for-users

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your model data from view to your template
you can have to function in your view that reffers to one page here is example

```
# here is first function that send information to your fields
# i suggest you to use id in url and here to recognize which record you are updating
def editbox(request,id)
    # here we get informations from model database
    data = yourmodel.objects.get(id=id) #here yourmodel is your actual model name that you have to import above
    return render(request,'updatedata.html',{"data":data}) # and here we pass to html


# secondly you have to update and edit your data
def FunctionName(request,id):
    updateme = yourmodel.objects.get(id=id) # here we have to use again to recognize which data we're updating
    form = yourupdateform(request.POST,instance=updateme) # it send data 
    if form.is_valid: 
        form.save()
        return redirect('logdata') # redirect if you want
```

and now you need to make your form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import yourmodel

class formname(forms.ModelForm):
    model=yourmodel
    fields="__all__" # this will update all the fields of model class
```

you have to edit urls to pass id from url to these functions to work

```
   # you need to have two function, one of them is for editing and ecyrything is there and other is just for update
   # replace your function name there
   path('edit/<int:id>',views.youreditfunction')
   path('update/<int:id>',views.yourupdatefunction')
```

now time to make html:

```
   <br><br>
    <h2 class="text-center">Edit Log Data</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <form action="/update/{{ data.id }}" method="post">
            <!-- here you can style your forms and etc i dont focus on here -->
            {% crf_token %}

            # here is an example of what you can do you can write as much as you want
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ data.username }}">

            <input type="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
    </div>
```

i think this way works but not 100%