# Allow users to sort in ascending order using radio button django

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a web page as shown below, the web page able to display the data in the form of a table, I have also implemented the search bar and the page filter and is both working, right now I am try to allow the users to sort the data in ascending order. For example, the customer name will start from A (Airasia) to Z(Zasia) and the part number will start from 1(01232) to 9(999). How do i do that and also at the same time when it is sort in ascending order, both the search bar and the filter pages is also working.

UPDATE: The Url is able to show the stuff that i click on but the data is just not sorting in order as shown in the image below.

[image]

views.py

```
    @login_required()
def ViewMCO(request):
    search_post = request.GET.get('q')
    if (search_post is not None) and search_post:
        allusername = Photo.objects.filter(Q(reception__icontains=search_post) | Q(partno__icontains=search_post) | Q(
            Customername__icontains=search_post) | Q(mcoNum__icontains=search_post) | Q(status__icontains=search_post)
                                           | Q(serialno__icontains=search_post))
        if not allusername:
            allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime")


    else:
        allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime")


    part = request.GET.get('p')
    if (part is not None) and part:
        allusername = Photo.objects.filter(Q(partno__icontains=part)).order_by("-partno")








    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(allusername, 6)
    try:
        allusername = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        allusername = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        allusername = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'allusername': allusername, 'query': search_post}
    return render(request, 'ViewMCO.html', context)
```

ViewMCO.html

```
    {% extends "customerbase.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <style>
    table {
        border-collapse:separate;
        border:solid black 1px;
        border-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
    }
    
    td, th {
        border-left:solid black 1px;
        border-top:solid black 1px;
    }
    
    th {
        border-top: none;
    }
    
    td:first-child, th:first-child {
         border-left: none;
    }

    .pagination a {
    padding: 10px;
    }

    .sort {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    }


    </style>
    <script>
      
    
     // Function to download table data into csv file
            function download_table_as_csv(table_id, separator = ',') {
                var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
                var csv = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
                    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                        var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
                        data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
                        row.push('"' + data + '"');
                    }
                    csv.push(row.join(separator));
                }
                var csv_string = csv.join('\n');
                var filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.style.display = 'none';
                link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            };

    </script>


       <div style="padding-left:16px">
         <br>
    
    
     <div class="form-block">
         <h6>Search for Part Number/ Serial Number/ Reception Number/ MCO Number/ Customer Name/ Status</h6>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'ViewMCO' %}" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'/>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

         <div class="sort">
           <h5 class="col-md-3">Sort By : </h5>


                <div id="sortBlock" class="col-md-9">
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'ViewMCO' %}" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.p }}'>
                   
                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="partno" name="sortType" value="partno">
                        <label for="partno">Part Number</label>
                    </div>

                     <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="serialno" name="sortType" value="serialno">
                        <label for="serialno">Serial Number</label>
                    </div>

                     <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="receptionno" name="sortType" value="receptionno">
                        <label for="receptionno">Reception Number</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="mcoNum" name="sortType" value="mcoNum">
                        <label for="mcoNum">MCO Number</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="Customername" name="sortType" value="Customername">
                        <label for="Customername">Customer Name</label>
                    </div>
                         <div class="sort">
                        <input type="Submit" value="Sort"/>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
         </div>
     </div>





       <table id="viewTable" class="m-2">
            <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="#" onclick="download_table_as_csv('viewTable');">Download as CSV</a>
           <br>
    
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Latest Log</th>
          <th>Part Number</th>
          <th>Serial Number</th>
          <th>Reception Number</th>
          <th>MCO Number</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
           {% for photo in allusername %}
    
    
      <tr>
            <td>{{photo.Datetime}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.partno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.serialno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.reception}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.mcoNum}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.Customername}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.status}}</td>


          <td>
          <form action="{% url 'customerdetails' photo.id %}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">View</button>
          </form>
          </td>
      </tr>
    
    {% endfor %}
    
    </table>
         <br>

  {% if allusername.has_other_pages %}

  <ul class="pagination pr-3 mr-1 ml-auto">

    {% if allusername.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&page={{ allusername.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in allusername.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if allusername.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if allusername.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&page={{ allusername.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}


    </div>
       </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @amadou sow, sorry to disturb you, not sure if can help me again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your views.py there is some logic problem because if a user tries to sort your data
by unexisting fields the you will have 500 error.i remove that bugs by doing this.
views.py

```
@login_required()
def ViewMCO(request):
    search_post = request.GET.get('q')
    if (search_post is not None) and search_post:
        allusername = Photo.objects.filter(Q(reception__icontains=search_post) | Q(partno__icontains=search_post) | Q(
            Customername__icontains=search_post) | Q(mcoNum__icontains=search_post) | Q(status__icontains=search_post)
                                           | Q(serialno__icontains=search_post))
        if not allusername:
            allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime")


    else:
        allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime")

    #new important part   
    part = request.GET.get('sortType')
    valid_sort = ["partno","serialno","receptionno","Customername","mcoNum"]
    if (part is not None) and part in valid_sort:
        allusername = allusername.order_by(part)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(allusername, 6)
    try:
        allusername = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        allusername = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        allusername = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'allusername': allusername, 'query': search_post,'order_by':part}
    return render(request, 'ViewMCO.html', context)
```

html
in sort by there is some modification to do.i change the value to value='{{ request.GET.sortType }}' and also i put action="" this means that use the current url.

```
<div class="sort">
           <h5 class="col-md-3">Sort By : </h5>


                <div id="sortBlock" class="col-md-9">
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.sortType }}'>
                   
                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="partno" name="sortType" value="partno">
                        <label for="partno">Part Number</label>
                    </div>

                     <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="serialno" name="sortType" value="serialno">
                        <label for="serialno">Serial Number</label>
                    </div>

                     <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="receptionno" name="sortType" value="receptionno">
                        <label for="receptionno">Reception Number</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="mcoNum" name="sortType" value="mcoNum">
                        <label for="mcoNum">MCO Number</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="Customername" name="sortType" value="Customername">
                        <label for="Customername">Customer Name</label>
                    </div>
                         <div class="sort">
                        <input type="Submit" value="Sort"/>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
         </div>
```

now we have to work on pagination(we have to add order_by to the pagination part)

```
{% if allusername.has_other_pages %}

  <ul class="pagination pr-3 mr-1 ml-auto">

    {% if allusername.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&sortType={{ order_by }}&page={{ allusername.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in allusername.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if allusername.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&sortType={{ order_by }}&page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if allusername.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&sortType={{ order_by }}&page={{ allusername.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

I think That all you need.if you have some questions please ask them in the comment below.

Comment: Hi, the data is still not sort in order, only the customer name is

Comment: this number that start with 2 23434534 is at the last when i sort via serial number, reception number and mco number

Comment: @Shadowwalker serial number, reception number and mco numbe are there char field or integerfield in the database ?

Comment: they are all textfield in my model

Comment: serial number is numeric, reception number is varchar, mco number is varchar in my database

Comment: @Shadowwalker Sorry it won't work .Django order stuff by there type .This is a problem of database design.if there are numbers then use number not textfield or charfield.

Comment: so in my model i should use numeric field?

Comment: @Shadowwalker I mean yes if there are number then it is better to use numeric field.but be carefull if you have already a lot of code that depends on that database.because you can have some problems.

Comment: @Shadowwalker is it working ?

Comment: yes it is working, thanks for your help

Comment: if possible can give me an upvote, i think this might be useful for the community

Comment: @Shadowwalker Yes it is an interesting question.i upvoted it.

Comment: If I want to sort from descending order is it just add a - in my valid sort like this: -date_joined

Comment: @Shadowwalker to do this you can do something like this `allusername = allusername.order_by("-"+part) `

Comment: ok, will try it and if i cant i will open another questions

Comment: do you know how to do barcode scanner, like when the user use a scanner, the mco number will automatically display on the screen

Comment: @Shadowwalker i know how to do qrcode scanner.for barcode i do not use it.refer to this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDIJ4GgKxR8&ab_channel=Pyplane

Comment: ah ic, i am going to use rasberry pi for barcode scanner'